# Values imported from other workbook differ

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a VBA module in Excel to populate a worksheets with data from another worksheet. It imports the data through code along these lines:

```
Src.Wd = Workbooks(WB_Src.Name).Sheets("Quote Product Associated View").Cells(Counter, SC_Wd).Value

Workbooks(WB_Calc.Name).Worksheets(WS_CalcData.Name).Cells(Counter, 7).Value = Src.Wd
```

Everything works fine with the import, except that the numbers in many cases differ slightly from the original data. The variables defined as `Integer` are fine, unsurprisingly, but those defined as `Single` have a tendency of varying very slightly if they have a decimal. **12.0** will, for instance, populate fine as **12.0**, while **16.08** turns into **16.079999923706**.

Any idea what the problem could be and how to remedy it? 
Do I need to include a truncation, or is there a simple way of getting it across right in the first place?

Comment: Excel uses Doubles internally, not Singles and I suspect it's that conversion that is at issue. Why don't you skip the variable and simply assign the value of one range to the other directly?

Comment: Aah, that could be it. I'd used the variables to make the whole thing more legible, but your suggestion makes more sense. Cheers, I'll try that.